# Null value in gcm message

Tags: php, android, json, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use a typical php backend using curl to send GCM push notifications to android devices.The php script is as follows :

```
<?php
//request url
$url    = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
//your api key
$apiKey = 'AIzaSyB-1uEai2WiUapxCs2Q0GZYzPu7Udno5aA';
//registration ids
$registrationIDs = array('APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...');
//payload data
$data   = array('score' => '1-0', 'scorer' => 'Ronaldo', 'time' => '44');

$fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
            'data' => $data);

//http header
$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
             'Content-Type: application/json');

//curl connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

I use a broadcast receiver in the client app :

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("score");
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());


        // Showing received message
        lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
```

From the result of the php script, I'm pretty sure that the json message is being sent properly. I also recive a notification in the registered device. But the thing is, I get a "null" message. As I'm just trying to print the string I receive, "null" gets printed. Is there something wrong with this statement : `String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("score");`? Or should I decode the json  in order to retrieve the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
$fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
            'data' => $data);
```

you have to make it like this:

```
$fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
            'data.score' => $data);
```

Comment: ok try "data.message" in php script and change your newMessage string to String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

Comment: Thanks for that. But I figured out that xmpp well suits my need. .

Comment: What was the solution? Still don't have it